# How to pass data from one form to another form's listView in windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two form named `Form1` and `Form2`. In `form2`, I have a `listView` named `listView1` and customized as details. In the `listView1` I have 5 column which are Id, Name, Address, Age, Date. In `Form1`, I have a button name `button1`. When I will click the button I want to pass `integer` value for `Age`, string value for `Name` and `Address` and current date and time into `Date` column. I also want to auto increment the Id . How can I implement all of this?

Comment: Have you tried a global variables?

Comment: `@Mark Karim` No. I have not. Can you tell me a little more about this? Exactly where should I put those variables?

Answer (score 0):

Please following the next suggestion:

Create a new Class

```
public class Details
{
public int Age {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

Then, make a new instance of *Details* Class into the Button1_Click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var details = new Details
    {
     Age = 22,
     Name = 'Rubel'
     Address='New York'
    }

    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(details);
    frm2.Show();    
}
```

- implementing detail class values into your *ListView*

Answer (score 0):

**Look at this short turotial:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhAsXHjBaxk

There was a man explaining how to use ListView...

You can add for the current Date:

```
DateTime Date;
Date=DateTime.Now;
```

or

```
string Date1;
Date1=DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

For auto increment Id u can create new Global class:

```
public class Global
    {
        static int ID_ = 0;
        public static int Id
        {
            get { return ++ID_; }
        }       
    }
```

Then call from Form1

```
int noumber1= Global.Id;
int noumber2= Global.Id;
.....
```